# How to remove color line examples label in google chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

how can I remove color lines examples in google chart? I mean line examples from the right side in the image attached

[image]

```
exampleChart.draw(view, {
        vAxis: {
            viewWindow: {
                min: 0
            },
            viewWindowMode: "explicit"
        }
    }, {
        legends: "none",
        curveType: "function",
        backgroundColor: "#000",
        fontSize: "18",
        colors: ["#000"],
        series: {
            1: {
                lineDashStyle: [0, 0]
            }
        },
        lineWidth: 1,
        chartArea: {
            width: "100%"
        });
```

Comment: What you did for far? Please share the Scrip you developed so far to achieve this

Comment: I created a chart!

Comment: there would be a script generated behind that. Can you please share it?

Comment: check above.....

Comment: Please try to change the lineWidth: 1 to lineWidth: 0 so should hide the line

Answer (score 1):

there are extra curly braces in your options definition
resulting in two objects instead of one
so the chart is using only the `vAxis` definition

```
{
    vAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
            min: 0
        },
        viewWindowMode: "explicit"
    }
}, {   // <-- remove these, add comma above
    legend: "none",
    curveType: "function",
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    fontSize: "18",
    colors: ["#000"],
    series: {
        1: {
            lineDashStyle: [0, 0]
        }
    },
    lineWidth: 1,
    chartArea: {
        width: "100%"
    });
```

see following snippet...

```
chart.draw(view, {
  vAxis: {
    viewWindow: {
      min: 0
    },
    viewWindowMode: "explicit"
  },
  legend: "none",
  curveType: "function",
  backgroundColor: "rgb(238, 238, 238)",
  fontSize: "10",
  colors: ["#176bad"],
  series: {
    1: {
      lineDashStyle: [0,0]
    }
  },
  lineWidth: 0,
  chartArea: {
    width: "100%"
  }
});
```

Comment: actually your solution works but now I do not have left side numbers, from 1 to 0, just empty space, but I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Please try below script,

```
exampleChart.draw(view, {
    vAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
            min: 0
        },
        viewWindowMode: "explicit"
    }
}, {
    legend: "none",
    curveType: "function",
    backgroundColor: "#000",
    fontSize: "18",
    colors: ["#000"],
    series: {
        1: {
            lineDashStyle: [0, 0]
        }
    },
    lineWidth: 1,
    chartArea: {
        width: "100%"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

That is called a "legend", and can be removed by adding `legend: "none"` to your settings as specified in [line charts configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options).

Comment: I did it but it is there again, lines didn't hide

Comment: chart.draw(view, {vAxis: {viewWindow: {min: 0},  viewWindowMode: "explicit"}}, {legend:"none", curveType: "function", backgroundColor: "rgb(238, 238, 238)", fontSize: "10", colors: ["#176bad"], series: {1: {lineDashStyle: [0,0]}}, lineWidth: 0, chartArea: {width: "100%"}});

Comment: @rick1 Please create a JSFiddle or include the full code needed (including every variable you're using) to get the chart you're seeing. Otherwise we can't help you.